# Why does npm start error after cloning gitlab repo - throw err;?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

$ npm start

> final-project@0.1.0 start
> node App.js

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'E:\Ridho\SanberCode\CONTEKAN\Sanber-MovGaming-main\final-project\App.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

I have tried to reinstall node js, and nothing happen.

Comment: Have you tried `npn install ` . I guess you need to install dependencies from your package.json

Answer (score 0):

just write in the terminal

```
npm install
```

it will install the dependencies